# UIRectEdgeNone makes NavigationBar and Tabbar darker

Tags: ios7, navigationbar, tabbar

I have an iOS 7 app that has a NavigationController inside TabbarController.
I then customize the bars background color

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

It runs fine. But if there's a `ViewController` that wants not to be covered by the bars, like this

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeTop;
```

Which means this ViewController does not want to be covered by the Tabbar. But it makes the Tabbar **darker** than normal

I think this is because I use custom color for the bars. How to fix ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It probably means that the there's nothing to show below the translucent tab bar. Set the tab bar `translucent` property to `NO`

Answer (score 8):

@rounak is right, maybe setting the tab or nav bar's translucency to NO tells iOS not to try to put another tab or nav bar under the current one, which makes it darker.

In the viewDidLoad, add this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO; // if you have a nav

self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO; // if you have a tab
```